# How to dynamically format currency in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**How do I dynamically format the currency in google sheets?**

**Current data**

| Platform | Currency | Budget | Amount Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TikTok | USD | 866.98 | 690.62 |
| TikTok | IDR | 6317.89 | 6317.89 |
| DV360 | THB | 3739.66 | 3438.48 |

**Desired Output**

| Platform | Currency | Budget | Amount Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TikTok | USD | USD 866.98 | USD 690.62 |
| TikTok | IDR | IDR 6317.89 | IDR 6317.89 |
| DV360 | THB | THB 3739.66 | THB 3438.48 |

Instead of using google apps script and manually format (since I have 1000 rows of data with multiple currency), I'm looking for cell formula approach in google sheets.

By referencing cell in "Currency", the values in "Budget" and Amount Spend" will be formatted accordingly.

Comment: Hi! Something like this: ```=I2&" " &TEXT(J2;"#,##0.00")``` where I2 is the currency symbol and J2 the value..

Comment: Hi, can you share what have you tried so far as well as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were using Excel, than the immediate answer would be to use Conditional Formatting. However, as you probably know, Google sheets does not allow conditional formating to be applied to `Number Format`. This leaves you with limited options. One key thing your post didn't include is that you probably wish to retain the *values* in the Bugdet and spend column. That makes it impossible to be be accomplished with a formula (happy to be proved incorrect if anyone knows something I don't...).

The only way to get the data to appears as you shows, as by using a formula to concatenate or join the cells. [See sample sheet with JoinValues tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13xyCIYhn-kcEE-8KE4IsT-LLwrv8shn574SV7IiBjWE/edit#gid=0).

### Better Data Structure

Not to be critical but the real issue you're facing is that your data is not in an optimal a structure. Your reporting requirement is very normal, you just need to unpivot your data. This would mean you would have one column with values/amoun, but you would add a column for ACTUAL or BUDGET  (this field is commonly called `version` or `category` for tools that present such information like BPC, Essbase, Tagetik). This would essentialy double the number or rows but offer you lots of pivoting options and methods of calculations. [See same spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13xyCIYhn-kcEE-8KE4IsT-LLwrv8shn574SV7IiBjWE/edit#gid=0) for what Unpivoted data would look like.

### Google Script

While the question did explicitly state WITHOUT Google Scripting, that would appear to be the only way to accomplish dynamic numeric formating by row. For anyone who finds this question and WOULD be open to scripting, this procedure below would accomplish the desired task [in this sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13xyCIYhn-kcEE-8KE4IsT-LLwrv8shn574SV7IiBjWE/edit#gid=1743840047).

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc*/

function fixFormat() {
  const currencyRange = "b2:b";// column b
  const valueRange = "c2:d"; //number columns
  const sheetName = "JoinValues";

  const dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var valueFormats = dataSheet.getRange(valueRange).getNumberFormats();
  var allCurrencies = dataSheet.getRange(currencyRange).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < allCurrencies.length; i++) {
    var currencyID = allCurrencies[i][0];
    if (currencyID != '') {
      for (var c = 0; c < valueFormats[i].length; c++) {
        valueFormats[i][c] = '"' + currencyID + '  "' + valueFormats[i][c]
      }
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  dataSheet.getRange(valueRange).setNumberFormats(valueFormats);
}
```

Comment: Hi @pgSystemTester, this is really good. I managed to execute it using the script just the way as I intended thanks man. 100%

I am just wondering if there is a new row of data with new currency, can it be automated without running the script everytime there is a new row of data?

Comment: Also @pgSystemTester, how to prevent the script from duplicating the format? The format will duplicate if i were to run it more than once

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something simpler, maybe try this workaround:

1. Create a 'store' sheet with
   [columns formatted for all possible currencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHclE.png). Note the column headers are the 'keys' for later.
2. In your main sheet, [use the 'FILTER' function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbYJG.png) to get the correct amounts based on the 'Currency' cell as the key.
3. The function will filter the corresponding cells accordingly. Try it!

You'll be able to operate on the value as well. Just pointing that out as it seems that may be why you'd prefer a 'format' rather than a 'CONCAT' of the currency and the number.

Also, if you'd like the formats in the manner in which you have described i.e. 'USD xxx' instead of '$ xxx', you can change this under ['Custom Currency'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3eWG.png). Just replace whatever signs they have there with 'USD', 'IDR' etc.